# Transactions not working OK in a PostgreSQL 11 stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

Postgres version:
**PostgreSQL 11.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,

compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit**

I have this stored procedure as shown below. This is just a test.
In that procedure I have 2 transactions:

- The first one is supposed to finish OK (i.e. I have written the code 
  so that it does not encounter any errors and so it will reach the `COMMIT` statement).
- The second transaction is supposed to fail as I intentionally 
  introduce an error in it (either via this `cast` there, or via an `INSERT` which causes PK violation).

Also, `yb.print_now` is a simple function which is just logging (inserting) messages to another table.

When I run this stored procedure I am expecting the updates and the logging of messages done by
the first transaction to be persisted in the database, even though the 2nd transaction failed.

But this is not what happens, both transactions seem to be rolled back.

1. Why is this? Am I doing something wrong?

And 2 more questions which are very important to me. :

2. When an error occurs (say like on line marked `***`) and when control reaches/jumps to the `EXCEPTION` block, I have the feeling that the transaction I was in is already rolled back before I even reach the `EXCEPTION` block. 
   So in the exception block I cannot do `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT` or anything 
   related to the transaction. Is that feeling correct?
3. Say I want to commit all the stuff done, despite of the error, is there a way I can do that?
   That's exactly what I want here. The error is an error... OK, but I want everything 
   which happened before I got the error to get committed.

How do I do this in Postgres 11?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE yb.test123()
     LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $procedure$ 

    DECLARE
        var_cnt int;
        c int;
    BEGIN

        START TRANSACTION; --- 1 ---

        raise notice '001.';

        PERFORM yb.print_now('===> 0010.');

        var_cnt = 0;

        update yb.mbb
        set the_price = the_price + 1   
        where 
        the_id = 23164;

        raise notice '002.';
        PERFORM yb.print_now('===> 0020.');

        raise notice '003.';
        PERFORM yb.print_now('===> 0030.');

        update yb.mbb
        set the_price = the_price + 1 
        where 
        the_id = 23164;

        COMMIT; --- 1 ---

        START TRANSACTION; --- 2 --- 

        c = cast('###a1e3Z' as int);  --- *** --- 

        raise notice '004.';
        PERFORM yb.print_now('===> 0040.');

        update yb.mbb
        set the_price = the_price + 1 
        where 
        the_id = 23164;

        -- insert into yb.mbb(the_id)
        -- values (23164); -- this will throw duplicate PK error

        raise notice '005.';
        PERFORM yb.print_now('===> 0050.');

        COMMIT; --- 2 ---



    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN

        raise notice 'We are in the exception block now.';
        -- ROLLBACK;
        -- COMMIT;

        RETURN;

    END

    $procedure$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens right at the start of your procedure, in the statement

```
START TRANSACTION;
```

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html) says:

> A new transaction is started automatically after a transaction is ended using these commands, so there is no separate `START TRANSACTION` command.

That should answer your first question.

As to the second, when you are in the exception branch, you have effectively rolled back the subtransaction that started with the `BEGIN` that belongs to the `EXCEPTION` clause (or after the last `COMMIT`). You are still in the transaction though, so you can issue `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK`.

To your third question: No, there is no way to commit “everything up to the last exception”. You could only have that by wrapping *every* statement in a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END` block, but that would seriously hurt your performance (apart from making your code unreadable).

Use `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END` blocks judiciously whenever you expect that a statement could fail.

Comment: "You could only have that by wrapping every statement" But even if I do this, aren't these nested transactions into the overall SP begin-end transaction? If so then whoever once the top-level transaction is rolled back, I think all the nested (sub) transactions will be rolled back too, no?

Comment: Yes. That is how you would like it to work, right? Still, don't use a subtransaction for each statement.

Comment: I don't get anything... This is totally confusing. Then how do we rollback just a nested transaction?

Comment: You start a nested transaction by starting a new block with `BEGIN`. All the commands until `END;` (which ends the nested transaction) will be part of the nested transaction. If the block has an `EXCEPTION` clause, an error will rollback the nested transaction.

Comment: Also, I notice if I have 2 nested transactions (BEGIN-EXC-END blocks) in my SP's main begin-exc-end block, and if an exception occurs in the 2nd nested block, the control goes to the outer exception block?! Why?

Comment: ... because you didn't catch the exception in the inner block.

Comment: I do catch it. I catch OTHERS.

Comment: You are mixing up a nested transaction or subtransaction (`BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END` block) and a transaction (ended with `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`).

Comment: Yes, I am mixing up. Thanks a lot. I think I start to get it now :)